# changing the color of individual data points flotr2

Tags: javascript, flotr

I was wondering if it was possible to change the color of individual data points. I have tried writing my own function into it like in tickFormatter, but it doesn't seem to be working. This is kinda what I'm talking about:

```
graph = Flotr.draw(container, [ 
            { data : dataset, label : 'Scores1', lines:{show:true}, 
                points: {
                    show: true,
                    color: function(o){
                        return 'yellow';
                    }
                }},
            { data : patient_average, label : 'Scores2',  lines:{show:true}, points: {show:true}},
            { data : overall_average, label : "Scores3", lines : {show:true, color:'#FFCD00'}, points: {show:true, color: '#FFCD00'}}
            ], {
```

Right now I was just trying to get it to show yellow so that I knew that the function would work. If that works I basically want it so that depending on what the value of the data point is I would color it into a certain color. But with the code above it just displays the points as grey meaning that it doesn't understand my code. Is this even possible? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use:
`lines:{show: true, fill: true, fillColor:'#000000'}` instead of your code.

It should work well. Same for points.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me there should be 'fillColor' instead of 'color'. Also check another property: 'fill: true'.